# I want to get and edit the values in spinner in the runtime

Tags: android, spinner

Hi
 I want to get the value in spinner in the run time the same i want to edit that get values.Is it is possible .... And tell me the way.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u google it before posting question here.
cmon do some research be4 posting question.
anyways i tyhink this might help you, if i got your question correctly.
http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=8

Answer (score 0):

Here you can update your Spinner Item Value at Run time also.

Try this Code...

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner sp;
    EditText et;
    List<String> li;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    li=new ArrayList<String>();
    li.add("Item 1");
    li.add("Item 2");
    li.add("Item 3");

    sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    add();

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    li.add(et.getText().toString());
    et.setText(null);
    add();
    }
    });
    }

    private void add() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,li);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    sp.setAdapter(adp);

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int pos1=position;
                String str1=sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
    }
```